# using multiprocessing when running a script

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, pool

i am running a script which takes in a url and downloads the file locally, and then passes the filename as an argument to a function.The problem is doing this takes a lot of time.So i tried using Threadpool,but this does not give any improvements.Am i doing this wrong, here is what it looks like.

```
pool = ThreadPool(processes=8)
ocr_result = pool.apply_async(download_file, (url,))
file_name = ocr_result.get()
async_result = pool.apply_async(return_label, (file_name,))
prediction, prediction_list  = async_result.get()
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you use `asyncio` + `aiohttp`

Comment: @hansolo Thanks,ill check it out,  Do you have sample code?

Comment: [This should get you started](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html)

Comment: okay thanks , ill look into it.

Comment: You are not using multiprocessing. You are using the pool, but you are running just one task synchronously.

Comment: You didn't use any concurrency here. After each appy_async you're waiting in blocking get for result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comment, there's a sample using `aiohttp` and `asyncio`:

```
def main():
    # limit concurrency
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)

    # login if required
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=connector) as sess:
        async with sess.post(
                LOGIN_URL, data=payload) as resp:

            # ensure login success
            assert resp.status == 200
            for url in download_links:
                await download(url, sess)
```

And your download function looks like:

```
async def download(url, sess):
    async with sess.get(url) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            # post process
```

Finally use a main loop:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for your time